# Type or Namespace name 'HTMLWorker' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am using iTextSharp version 4.1.6 in my application. My using includes both itextsharp.text and itextsharp.text.pdf.   I am trying to follow guidance from stackoverflow on creating a PDF from an html page. This requires that I use an itextsharp object called HTMLWorker.  However the intellisence shows no such class.  When I manually type in "HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(doc);" I get an error "Type or Namespace name 'HTMLWorker' could not be found.  Are you missing a using directive or a reference?"  Can anyone identify which using or reference I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the full namespace is: `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker` ([found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/203481/HTML-convert-to-PDF-using-itextsharp)).

Admittedly the documentation seems to be almost nonexistent and this link wasn't easy to find.

EDIT: I downloaded the dll and decompiled it, this is the correct namespace.

Comment: That did it. Thanks loads. Someone on the other thread complained that no one showed the using statements in their code examples. The OP thought he was referring to the using statement within the code. I think he meant the using directives, because that is an issue I've noted as well.  Again thanks a lot for getting me past this hurdle.

Comment: @user1161391 No problem. If helped you, be sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.